# How long does it take to process an account deletion?

Tags: support, deleted-users

I requested my account to be deleted yesterday and followed all the procedures listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: It's a weekend. Wait until Monday as a staff member has to press a few buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would care. Why not just stop using/logging into your account and forget about it?

Answer (score 12):

First of all, deletion requests have a *built-in delay*, to give you a chance to reconsider. Account deletions are rather permanent, so Stack Exchange wants you to be *sure*.

Next, the deletion request will be handled by a human, an employee at Stack Exchange. That means you'll have to wait for a working day before it can be processed.

So, in all, you'll have to be patient a little longer and at least wait out Monday!