# Account deletion taking too long - should I open up a GDPR request instead

Tags: support, accounts

It has now been at least three working days since I requested my account to be deleted. I am now wondering whether it is worth considering submitting a GDPR request in addition, even though that increases the amount of work for everyone involved. What are the main Pros and cons if this, both for me and any (European based) user who wants to leave the site in future?

Comment: @Tom I expect them to speed up the normal delete process in future if enough people start doing it .... :-)

Comment: Is the current delay illegal? Cause honestly, I feel like catering to the needs of people who want to leave the platform is not the kind of important improvements they will want to focus on :/. (I get why you wanna push it... I'm just trying to be realistic :/ )

Comment: I asked a question [very similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390840/is-the-account-removal-process-gdpr-compliant) to this recently

Comment: doing a gdpr request could just slow down the entire process as they might need to take care of that before they take care of the deletion request.

Comment: @Patrice no, the delay is not illegal. I understand that ``` I feel like catering to the needs of people who want to leave the platform is not the kind of important improvements they will want to focus on```, which is why I'm wondering if making a request which does need implementing may give a little push

Comment: @Displayname oh 100% with you there :). I'm just trying to frame the "*I expect them to speed up the normal delete process*" with the proper expectations ^^. Good luck to get it all wiped :)

Comment: GDPR recommends 30 days for deletion requests, however, depending on the complexity it can take up to 60 days - in additional [https://gdpr-info.eu/art-12-gdpr/ ]

Comment: @Matthew Up to 90 days, not 60

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385403/account-not-deleted-after-24h-with-active-session?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @NickA I had meant to say with an additional 60 days, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: GDPR gives you an upper limit. If you fear that the normal process will exceed this limit, do it.

Comment: Why are you in such a hurry? It will get deleted. It takes some time as it is not automatic process [How long does it take to process an account deletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269007/4267244) If anything GDPR request can slow deletion not make it faster.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "If anything GDPR request can slow deletion not make it faster. " Citation needed. GDPR gives an upper limit. If the deletion would usually be slower than the limit set by the GDPR, it might also make it faster (increase the priority).

Comment: @Trilarion Plain logic... deletion is one task, collecting data is additional task. Limit set by GDPR is 30 days. I believe account deletions at SO are much faster than that.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a GDPR request could end up delaying the process even more as it is likely there are other things involved with it that could end up taking longer.

They are given 30 days for a normal request and it can be extended given the complexity.

[article 12.3](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-12-gdpr/)

> "...without undue delay and in any event within one month of receipt of the request. That period may be extended by two further months where necessary, taking into account the complexity and number of the requests."

[right to erasure](https://www.threatstack.com/blog/gdpr-what-is-the-right-to-erasure)

> Confirm receipt of the request from the data subject to erase their data with a realistic erasure completion time frame. Nobody likes to be ignored, and responding to the request with a genuine notice of action is only fair. Under Article 12.3 of the GDPR, you have 30 days to provide information on the action your organization will decide to take on a legitimate erasure request. This timeframe can be extended up to 60 days depending on the complexity of the request.

Comment: "They are given 30 days" as far as I can tell that isn't true. The 30 days count for data request, but not for deletion requests. All the resources/guide lines I found say "no undue delay" without outlining a time-frame. Can you link your source please, would be interesting to read.

Comment: @Tom The relevant article is [12.3](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-12-gdpr/): *"...without undue delay and in any event* ***within one month of receipt of the request***. *That period may be extended* ***by two further months*** *where necessary, taking into account the complexity and number of the requests."*

Comment: @NickA That's a rather broad paragraph and it says the scope is from article 15 to 22, but article 17, the article about deletion, denies undue delays. So I wonder if article 17 is exempt there.

Comment: @Tom It says from 15-22 so 17 is explicitly included, the lack of definition for what constitutes an undue delay isn't relevant (to whether or not it's included, it may be relevant to the question)

Comment: [GDPR.eu](https://gdpr.eu/right-to-be-forgotten/) states: *"“Undue delay” is considered to be about a month."* towards of the end of the first paragraph of **What is the right to be forgotten?**